# How to skip sequence numbes in Cirqus

Tags: cirqus

I deleted a few events from my event store but now I get exceptions like this:

`System.ApplicationException: Tried to apply event with sequence number 180 to aggregate root with ID 55b43b9e-cd9a-4db9-9b86-78feb7043051 with current sequence number 15. Expected an event with sequence number 16.`

How can I ignore exceptions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't..... Cirqus is very very strict about its sequence numbers, which is to guarantee that aggregate roots are hydrated to a correct state and are impossible to hydrate into some state that they never actually were in.

This means that if you need to "delete" events, you cannot just remove the events from the event store.

I've tried once that some logic went awry and accidentally generated 50000 events while the system was running and the users kept working, which we then removed by replicating the events (using `EventReplicator`) to a new event store, decorating the destination `IEventStore` with a "rewriter", that would then ignore certain events and rewrite all sequence numbers as necessary.

It was pretty hard to get right though.

Do you really need to delete the events? Can't you e.g. append some corrective events to the problematic aggregate roots' event streams?